# Setting startup position of task notifier

Tags: c#, wpf

How to set the taskbar notifier startup position. Because it is working properly on some system, But on some system, it goes below the taskbar or disappear.[image: ScreenShot for same.]

**Code:**

```
<tn:TaskbarNotifier x:Class="LeadAlert.Main"
    xmlns:tn="clr-namespace:WPFTaskbarNotifier;assembly=WPFTaskbarNotifier"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Lead Alert" Height="240" Width="370" WindowStyle="None" Topmost="True" ResizeMode="NoResize" Background="Transparent" 
    AllowsTransparency="True" ShowInTaskbar="False" MouseMove="WinMain_MouseMove" 
    x:Name="WinMain" Icon="/LeadAlert;component/LeadAlert.ico" Closed="WinMain_Closed" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" >
```

Comment: You will need to post your current positioning code/XAML

Comment: Added the code of xaml.